GUI Not Displaying All Components (C++)
I am using Visual Studio 2022
Here is the code for the mainframe.
#include "MainFrame.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>

MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title) {
    wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this);

    wxButton* button = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "Button", wxPoint(150, 50), wxSize(100, 35));

    wxCheckBox* checkBox = new wxCheckBox(panel, wxID_ANY, "CheckBox", wxPoint(550, 55));

    wxStaticText* staticText = new wxStaticText(panel, wxID_ANY, "Static Text - NOT editable", wxPoint(120, 150));
}

The code runs 100% fine, however when my GUI pops up when I run on debug, the GUI only displays the button, but not the text or the checkbox.


They are there in that little white square in the upper-left corner. You need to give them the proper size.

@Calax, you really should look into sizers. Take a look here: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_sizer.html and here: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/overview_sizer.html

Related: If Windows, it's best and newer to use WinUI3.

You need to make the panel bigger in order for the controls you place in it to be seen. You currently use mxDefaultSize, which is pretty small, as can be seen in the top left corner of your picture.
The constructor you use is:
wxPanel::wxPanel(
    wxWindow* parent,
    wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY,
    const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
    const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,       // <- set this to something bigger
    long style = wxTAB_TRAVERSAL,
    const wxString& name = wxPanelNameStr 
)

Example:
wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(
    this,
    wxID_ANY,
    wxDefaultPosition,
    {1000, 1000}
);


Easy fix, I switched the wxPanel constructor for this:
wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(
    this,
    wxID_ANY,
    wxDefaultPosition,
    {1000, 1000}
);

And changed the pointer on the wxButton from 'this' to 'panel' and now everything appears as intended. Here is the new code:
#include "MainFrame.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>


MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title) {
    wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(
        this,
        wxID_ANY,
        wxDefaultPosition,
        { 2000, 2000 }
    );

    wxButton* button = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ANY, "Button", wxPoint(150, 50), wxSize(120, 50));

    wxCheckBox* checkBox = new wxCheckBox(panel, wxID_ANY, "CheckBox", wxPoint(550, 55));

    wxStaticText* staticText = new wxStaticText(panel, wxID_ANY, "Static Text - NOT editable", wxPoint(120, 150));
}

Thank you for your help everyone, much appreciated. :)
